# MySQL join with a distinct on two fields and a union

Tags: mysql

I have created this select with a union and two distinct fields.  The return is not showing only distinct data it is showing multiple shipment i'ds   I am not sure how to fix it and thoughts?

```
FROM
    cs.acct_sales_daily_extract2 sa
    inner JOIN
        ( 
               select distinct shipmentid, GPRecDate 
                from custom_cs.apj 
                where apdelay > 0 
                                                        
                union 
                
                select distinct shipmentid, 
                    GPRecDate 
                from custom_cs.arh 
                where ardelay > 0 
        ) shd on sa.shipment_id = shd.shipmentid
```

Example data...

```
1000162 173 173 TNME    85  20210706    IM  09735ZZ 13411   HOME DEPOT  0.00    0.00    90.00   90.00   -90.00  -90.00  0.0000  0.00    0.00    1000162         2021-07-06 21:11:27 482942  1000162 2021-07-06
1000162 173 173 TNME    85  20210618    IM  09735ZZ 13411   HOME DEPOT  3020.67 3020.67 3418.50 3418.50 -397.83 -397.83 -0.1317 0.00    1.00    1000162         2021-06-18 21:10:54 474954  1000162 2021-07-06
1000197 119 119 VAPT    100 20210630    TR  00426ZZ 10852   CV INTERNATIONAL    0.00    0.00    10.00   10.00   -10.00  -10.00  0.0000  0.00    0.00    1000197         2021-06-30 21:11:02 481508  1000197 2021-06-30
1000197 119 119 VAPT    100 20210620    TR  00426ZZ 10852   CV INTERNATIONAL    1365.40 1365.40 952.75  952.75  412.65  412.65  0.3022  0.00    1.00    1000197         2021-06-20 21:13:07 475387  1000197 2021-06-30
1000199 119 119 VAPT    100 20210630    TR  00426ZZ 10852   CV INTERNATIONAL    0.00    0.00    30.00   30.00   -30.00  -30.00  0.0000  0.00    0.00    1000199         2021-06-30 21:11:02 481507  1000199 2021-06-30
1000199 119 119 VAPT    100 20210620    TR  00426ZZ 10852   CV INTERNATIONAL    1500.40 1500.40 1072.75 1072.75 427.65  427.65  0.2850  0.00    1.00    1000199         2021-06-20 21:13:07 475388  1000199 2021-06-30
1000227 180 180 ILCH    20  20210811    IM  57193ZZ 11411   TOP SHELF   0.00    0.00    66.50   66.50   -66.50  -66.50  0.0000  0.00    0.00    1000227         2021-08-11 21:12:25 501018  1000227 2021-08-11
1000227 180 180 ILCH    20  20210628    IM  57193ZZ 11411   TOP SHELF   3141.65 3141.65 2547.24 2547.24 594.41  594.41  0.1892  0.00    1.00    1000227         2021-06-28 21:11:40 479037  1000227 2021-08-11
1000233 177 177 KYLX    181 20210630    IM  11703ZZ 10051   JOHNS MANVILLE  657.00  657.00  -68.42  -68.42  725.42  725.42  1.1041  0.00    0.00    1000233         2021-06-30 21:11:02 481135  1000233 2021-10-22
1000233 177 177 KYLX    181 20210817    IM  11703ZZ 10051   JOHNS MANVILLE  -657.00 -657.00 0.00    0.00    -657.00 -657.00 1.0000  0.00    0.00    1000233         2021-08-17 21:12:19 503628  1000233 2021-10-22
1000233 177 177 KYLX    181 20210615    IM  11703ZZ 10051   JOHNS MANVILLE  3932.50 3932.50 4597.07 4597.07 -664.57 -664.57 -0.1690 0.00    1.00    1000233         2021-06-15 21:10:42 473461  1000233 2021-10-22
```

Comment: Can you include column names with your sample data. There are a lot of columns and guessing isn't going to do us much good. As for your `distinct` know that each individual SELECT is going to apply a distinct on its own and then those two results are going to be union'd together. I would anticipate every distinct `shipmentid` available in both tables.

Comment: `select distinct shipmentid, GPRecDate` provides distinct for columns pair `(shipmentid, GPRecDate)` values whereas each separate column may contain duplicates.

Comment: shipmentid GPRecDate
1000003 2021-09-06
1000003 2021-09-06
1000024 2021-07-06
1000024 2021-07-06
1000049 2021-10-22
1000049 2021-10-22
1000049 2021-10-22
1000053 2021-06-10
1000053 2021-06-10
1000053 2021-06-10
1000053 2021-07-02
1000053 2021-07-02
1000053 2021-07-02
1000053 2021-10-21
1000053 2021-10-21
1000053 2021-10-21
1000053 2022-06-13
1000053 2022-06-13
1000053 2022-06-13
1000071 2021-07-02
1000071 2021-07-02
1000074 2021-07-26
1000074 2021-07-26

Comment: I narrowed it down to just two fields.  Shipmentid and GPRecDate.